# how to add theme to div in angular material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

this is the code that needs to be changed is class="header1 fuse-navy-600">

```
  <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="main-card">


                <div class="header1 fuse-navy-600">
                    <div class="title1">
                        <mat-icon class="logo-icon s-32 mr-16 mat-icon material-icons ng-trigger ng-trigger-animate"
                            role="img" aria-hidden="true">shopping_basket
                        </mat-icon>
                        {{ title }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="mode-container" *ngIf="processedEntryForm && myForm">
                        <span class="mode">
                            <p class="mode-text">Mode: {{ eventType.valueOf() |
                            titlecase }}</p>
                            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-mode" *ngIf="eventCode == 'VIEW'">visibility
                            </mat-icon>
                            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-mode" *ngIf="eventCode == 'DELETE'"
                                aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">delete_outline </mat-icon>
                            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-mode" *ngIf="eventCode == 'MODIFY'"
                                aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">create
                            </mat-icon>
                            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-mode" *ngIf="eventCode == 'PROCESSPENDING' || eventCode == 'PROCESS' ">build</mat-icon>

                            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-mode" *ngIf="eventCode == 'ADD'">add</mat-icon>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKrvZ.png)
how will i add theme to a div and be able to change the header fuse-navy-600 color

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you using the theme Angular Fuse? If so in which version? What color in the color themes provided by Fuse would you like to change your div to?

Comment: @Ocunidee yes and the newest version and the color is the same as primary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm seeing in the documentation of the latest Fuse theme which uses Tailwind CSS (http://angular-material.fusetheme.com/ui/colors), to change the background-color of a div to the primary color, you can replace the `fuse-navy-600` class in the html by `bg-primary`. In case you want to choose a specific hue of the primary color, you can specify it in this manner: `bg-primary-300`

Comment: it didnt work unfournately

Comment: Are you sure you are on the last version of fuse theme?

Comment: yes and if you would like i can share my discord name and i can screenshare my code so you can check where its not working